# Honor 3c debug mode not work for adb

Tags: android, adb

i have huawei honor 3c drivers are installed debug mode is active but did not show when i run android app. before this i use nexus 5 it work fine.
please tel me what to do. Thanks

Comment: Install the correct USB ADB device driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was connecting with wrong usb connecting method i just change to usb flash drive and it worked.